# Iterate nested lists in dictionary

Tags: dictionary, ansible, jinja2

Given the dictionary

```yaml
sudoers_include:
  sudofile1:
    privileges:
      - name: "%technodrome"
        paths: 
          - "ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL"
```

The task

```yaml
- name: gen /etc/sudoers.d file
  template:
    src: sudoers_d_file.j2
    dest: "/etc/sudoers.d/{{ item.key }}"
  loop: "{{ sudoers_include | dict2items }}"
```

and the template

```yaml
shell> cat sudoers_d_file.j2
{% for item in item.value.privileges | default([]) %}
{{ item.name }} {{ item.paths }}
{% endfor %}
```

give

```bash
shell> cat /etc/sudoers.d/sudofile1
%technodrome ['ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL']
```

I should get

```bash
%technodrome ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate also the *paths*

```yaml
{% for item in item.value.privileges | default([]) %}
{% for i in item.paths %}
{{ item.name }} {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

(not tested)

Comment: tested and working... 
thanks !
I missed completely to iterate over values :)

Comment: Make it always [mre]. Problems pop up better when minimal.